# Wired Xbox controller not working Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I'm running a dual boot system with Windows 11. My Xbox controller works fine in Windows.

The controller doesn't respond (but is recognised) if booting up into Ubuntu.

lsusb at a terminal gives:
"Bus 001 Device 008: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller"

However if I boot into windows first, and then restart into Ubuntu, the controller does work correctly!

Any help appreciated.

I've tried the usual unplugging and different USB ports but this doesn't change the above behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Windows Fast Startup feature. When you shut down Windows, it doesn't really shut down. When you reboot, it does. As simple as that.

Comment: Fast startup is not enabled. The problem is when booting directly into Ubuntu first, the controller is not working.